# Linux - Handle process termination

Tags: linux, unix

I need to watch for a process with a known PID in Linux. Once it is terminated want to execute a command with reason of termination.

**Questions**

1. How to subscribe to process health **rather than polling** (e.g. watch
   command)?
2. Where to inject the event handler in OS' user space?
3. How to detect the termination/failure reason inside handler?

**Note**

- The process I intend to keep a tab on is not forked as a child process of some parent through which it can be monitored.
- The process type is generic (good number of them are daemons)

Comment: Is your process the parent?  You can call `waitpid` when `SIGCHLD` is delivered.

Comment: No. The two processes are independent. (I add this detail to my question).

Comment: When you say unix, do you really mean linux? Are you asking about any generic process or a specific kind of process, for example, is it a daemon?

Comment: _When you say unix, do you really mean linux?_ **Yes unix/linux.** & _Generic or Specific Process?_ **I am dealing with all kinds; good number of them are daemons**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get that kind of control over another process, is to use ptrace(2) to trace the target process.  You would use `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid)` to attach to the process, after which you effectively become the target process's parent (and can use `wait` or more `ptrace` calls to figure out what the process is doing).